# undefined reference to some of the opencv functions

Tags: c++, eclipse, opencv, linker

I'm trying to compile the `'motemple.c'` that comes with the opencv samples in Ubuntu 14.04 environment. I think that opencv has been properly installed; most of the programs are running as expected. However, when compiling the above mentioned file, an error "undefined reference" is raised for several functions. Below is the output of the compilation:

```
Building target: ACTION_detection1
Invoking: Cross G++ Linker
g++ -L/usr/local/lib -o "ACTION_detection1"  ./opencvexample/MotionSegmentation.o   -lopencv_core -lopencv_photo -lopencv_videoio -lopencv_videostab -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_ml -lopencv_shape -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_superres -lopencv_ts -lopencv_video -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_legacy -lopencv_flann
./opencvexample/MotionSegmentation.o: In function `update_mhi':
/media/thanuja/DTR_DATA/ACTION-TV/ACTIONDETECTION/Implementations/ACTION_detection1/Debug/../opencvexample/MotionSegmentation.cpp:103: undefined reference to `cvUpdateMotionHistory'
/media/thanuja/DTR_DATA/ACTION-TV/ACTIONDETECTION/Implementations/ACTION_detection1/Debug/../opencvexample/MotionSegmentation.cpp:105: undefined reference to `cvUpdateMotionHistory'
/media/thanuja/DTR_DATA/ACTION-TV/ACTIONDETECTION/Implementations/ACTION_detection1/Debug/../opencvexample/MotionSegmentation.cpp:114: undefined reference to `cvCalcMotionGradient'
/media/thanuja/DTR_DATA/ACTION-TV/ACTIONDETECTION/Implementations/ACTION_detection1/Debug/../opencvexample/MotionSegmentation.cpp:123: undefined reference to `cvSegmentMotion'
/media/thanuja/DTR_DATA/ACTION-TV/ACTIONDETECTION/Implementations/ACTION_detection1/Debug/../opencvexample/MotionSegmentation.cpp:149: undefined reference to `cvCalcGlobalOrientation'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [ACTION_detection1] Error 1
```

As it can be seen, I have linked all the opencv libraries to mu Eclipse project. I also tried the command line solution provided [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/239891/opencv-program-wont-compile-quantal), but still get the same error.

Comment: Hard to tell what the problem is. What do you mean by you "think that opencv has been properly installed"? How did you install it?

Comment: Sorry if the terminology is confusing. I followed the guidelines in opencv documentation and simple programmes like viewing images, playing videos and colour enhancements etc., work fine. The issue seems to be with these  set of motion segmentation functions.

Comment: The same error was raised in the windows environment as well. However adding the linker library opencv_video resolved the issues. The issue in Ubuntu still remains even with the addition of this library. Do you have any idea on how to resolve this?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

they have been replaced to the `opencv_contrib` from the main repository. You can find them in the [`optflow`](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib/blob/master/modules/optflow/include/opencv2/optflow/motempl.hpp) module.

Notice: `cvUpdateMotionHistory`, `cvCalcMotionGradient`, etc. is the name of OpenCV 1.x API functions, they are now obsoleted/outdated so try to avoid them by replacing to `cv::updateMotionHistory`, `cv::calcMotionGradient`, etc.

Comment: Thanks. I believe this is the case. The working one I tried is an old version of opencv.